# solution of $y''+\frac{1}{x}y'-y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the second order differential equation $\Delta u-u=0$ in the region $R^n\setminus B(0,1)$. To make it simpler, I tried the case $n=2$. I assume the solution should be a function of radius r, and used the polar coordinate. Finally, it reduced to solve the function $y^{\prime\prime}+\frac{1}{x}y^{\prime}-y=0$. Any way to write the explicit form of the solution?

Comment: If you allow Bessel functions, then "yes."  If you multiply by $x^2$, then this is Bessel's equation with $\alpha=0$.  Wiki has a decent article.

Answer (score 1):

According to Mathematica the solution is
$$
y(x) = aI_0(x)+bY_0(-ix)
$$
where $I_0$ and $Y_0$ are Bessel functions and $a$ and $b$ are constants. We can also rewrite $Y_0$ in terms of $K_0$
$$
Y_0(ix) = c K_0(x) + d I_0(x)
$$
giving the solution
$$
y(x) = eI_0(x)+fK_0(x)
$$
for other constants $c,d,e,f$.

Comment: Can $Y_0(-ix)$ be rendered in terms of $K_0$?

Comment: Yes, that looks better without the imaginary argument. Thanks.